# Timeline with arrows

Tags: timeline

I want to create something like this.

[image]

Sadly, i have no idea where to start. Is there a special package for something like this? 
Sorry and thank you in advance!

Comment: this can be drawn with the `tikz` package ... also with `pstrick`. use some similar question (listed at right side of site window) for start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Zarko says, there are many ways of drawing such diagrams, here is one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,bullet/.style={fill=black,circle,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=1.2pt}]
\draw[thick,-{Triangle[open]}] (-0.2,0) -- (8.5,0);
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw ({(\X-1)*4},0.1) -- ({(\X-1)*4},-0.1);
\draw[thick,dashed] ({(\X-1)*4},0) -- ++(0,2)
node[above,bullet]{\X};}
\node [double arrow, fill=gray!60,minimum height=3.6cm] at (2,1) {Fast Forwarding};
\node [double arrow, fill=gray!60,minimum height=3.6cm] at (6,1) {Monitoring};
\draw[orange,very thick,latex-latex] (0,-0.7) -- (8,-0.7)
node[midway,bullet]{4};
\node[anchor=north] at (0,0) {0};
\node[anchor=north east] at (8,0) {Time};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]